# Regular expression to match exact url path on different hosts

Tags: regex

need help to create regular expression matching string

```
www.*.abc.*/somestring
```

Here * is wild card it can be anyhing like 
us, uk

or com, edu

like

```
 www.us.abc.com/somestring
www.uk.abc.edu/somestring
```

Comment: Can your TLD be .co.uk or .com.au, this would make a difference to your solution

Comment: What is TLD?
Actually URL can contain co.uk so I am trying with 
www\.[^.]+\.abc\.[^.]+\.[^.]+

Comment: If I want to do a match of any character the how can I do that.
Suppose I have url www.abc.co.uk/12=1231&wwd=13&eef=1231231
How to match the string "12=1231&wwd=13&eef=1231231"
there is not constraint on this, it can contain any number/kind of characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put `[^.]+` instead of asterisks and `\.` instead of dots, and you'll be done.

```
www\.[^.]+\.abc\.[^.]+/somestring
```

`[^.]` matches any non-dot, `[^.]+` matches a string of nondots with at least one character. `\.` matches a dot, because `.` matches any character.

Answer (score 1):

```
www\.([a-z]{2})\.abc\.(com|edu)/(.+)
```

You can then extends this regex to include other [valid generic top-level domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain) (net, org, ...)

```
www\.([a-z]{2})\.abc\.(com|edu|org|net)/(.+)
```

You will get the [Country code top-level domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country-code_top-level_domain) in the group number 1, the top-level domain in group 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regular expression:

```
^www\.\w+\.abc\.\w+\/\w+$
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a URL, it can match any `a-z` character, or `0-9`, or a dash (`-`). Each component has at least one character, so use `+` as the multiplier. Currently, tlds are only a-z, but this regex is a bit more robust (you never know!):

```
/www\.[-a-z0-9]+?\.abc\.[-a-z0-9]+?\/somestring/
```

It assumes nothing about the length of each component, and that it's all lowercase.

Comment: You are right, but what if you want to limit yourself to the country codes or top level domain names (and only those ones)? [az] would suffice.

Comment: [a-z], but otherwise you're right. I mention that in my answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
www\.\w+\.abc\.\w+\/somestring
```

I do recommend to use this [Online RegEx builder](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to learn how it works